# Show Multiple Alert Controller on particular button click?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a label which asks a questions and user needs to answer by tapping on "**YES**" or "**NO**" button. if user clicks directly on NEXT Button the alert pops up saying `Choose Yes or No` if user selects Yes then he gets a new sub question there itself , if user clicks on NEXT without answering the sub question another alertView should pop up. On both the Condition only one alert view is displayed. help plz
heres the code

```
 -(IBAction)btnNextClicked:(id)sender {

    activeButton = sender;
    if (([_txtOwnerShipPercentage.text isEqualToString:@" "] || _txtOwnerShipPercentage.text==nil || _txtOwnerShipPercentage.text.length==0) && (activeButton.tag == 1)) {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Select Ownership Percentage" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
       [alertController addAction:okAction];
       [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (activeButton.tag == 0){
       UIAlertController *alertController2 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Select 'YES' or 'No'" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
       UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
      [alertController2 addAction:okAction];
      [self presentViewController:alertController2 animated:YES completion:nil];

   }
}
```

and i have set tags to YES and No Button... 1 & 2 respectively.
activebutton is nothing but globally declared UIButton

Comment: you mean to say `Alert` works only once, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code of how you can manage two or multiple alert controllers in one context according to your requirement.

```
    //declare first alert controller
    UIAlertController *alertviewcontroller1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert 1"
                                                                   message:@"This is an action sheet of alert 1"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    //declare second alert controller
    UIAlertController *alertviewcontroller2 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert 2"
                                                                                  message:@"This is an action sheet of alert 2"
                                                                           preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    //declare first alert controller action with hendler
    UIAlertAction *firstActionOfAlert1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                              //Present second alert controller when user taps on 'YES' of first alert controller.
                                                              [self presentViewController:alertviewcontroller2 animated:YES completion:nil];
                                                          }];

    //declare second alert controller action with hendler
    UIAlertAction *firstActionOfAlert2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YES"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {


                                                          }];

    //add both actions relatively
    [alertviewcontroller1 addAction:firstActionOfAlert1];
    [alertviewcontroller1 addAction:firstActionOfAlert2];

    //Present first alert controller
    [self presentViewController:alertviewcontroller1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

the above solution will not work in case if previous alert is not fully presented or without tapping an action in alertView. Use this method for that,

```
if (self.presentedViewController & !self.presentedViewController.isBeingPresented) {
        [self.presentedViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```